# Bugsnag not notifying completed 404 error rails rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine, rubymine-7, bugsnag

Bugsnag is reporting other errors like 501 internal server error but not 404 error as described in the docs. In gem file i have

```
gem 'bugsnag'
```

in Initializer folder i have bugsnag.rb

```
Bugsnag.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = "abc................"
end
```

Comment: "eBugsnag" is that a typo? Are rescuing somehow the AR errors? May be in application controller?

Comment: thanks @Anton yes it was a typo.